# How do I compare two list with a condition to check?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to implement an attendance system. I have two list which I already convert them to Unix timestamp. One list contains a fix timetable and the other is the log of the student if they clock in.

For example the timetable list might include

```
timetable[1519650000, 1519740000, 1519743600]
timetableEnd[1519653600, 1519743600, 1519747200]

log[1519739987, 1519744087]
```

In the human readable way but not in the code

```
timetable[2018-02-26 13:00:00, 2018-02-27 14:00:00, 2018-02-27 15:00:00]
timetableEnd[2018-02-26 14:00:00, 2018-02-27 15:00:00, 2018-02-27 16:00:00]


log[2018-02-27 13:59:47, 2018-02-27 15:08:07]
```

Is the a way to loop every single log element to check with timetable element that will agree this condition

> a <= x <= b

```
Where a = timetable begin time - 5mins    
      x = log time    
      b = end time for timetable time

Example: (1519650000 - 300) <= x <= 1519653600
        return false since log doesnt have a value that satisfy this
```

Can I get some advice or a guidance on how should I proceed this.

Comment: Where did 1519653600 come from?

Comment: @glibdud As mentioned I have converted the timestamp to Unix timestamp for easier calculation

Comment: Right, but I don't see 1519653600 anywhere in your sample data

Comment: Its the first in the timetable

Comment: Where? I see 1519743600, but not 1519653600.

Comment: Oh right that is the end time for one hour slot which I forget to mention so lets say class starts 1 pm it will end 2 pm.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to look like? The values of all log entries that fall within any start-end period? Indexes into the `log` list? Tuples of log entry and matching start time? Just a true-false for each log entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build pairs of neighbors of a list using the pattern `zip(a[:-1], a[1:])` and you can pair up the elements of two equally long lists using `zip(a, b)`.  Using these two things you can try this:

```
if all(start-300 <= log_element <= end
       for ((start, end), log_element) in zip(
           zip(timetable[:-1], timetable[1:]), log)):
    print("All logs are in their boundaries.")
```

In your case this will not succeed because `log[1]` is not between `timetable[1]-300` and `timetable[2]`.

In case you are not familiar with Python's elegant functional style, you might find it easier to understand it phrased this (less elegant) way:

```
def all_logs_in_boundaries(timetable, log):
    for ((start, end), log_element) in zip(
         zip(timetable[:-1], timetable[1:]), log)):
        if not (start-300 <= log_element <= end):
            return False
    return True  # or: print("All logs are in their boundaries.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use datetime?
Use something like this

```
import datetime
logtime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x)
begintime = datatime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a)
arrivaltime = logtime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
return (arrivaltime <= logtime and logtime <= begintime)
```

logtime is the datetime from x
begintime is the datetime from a
and arrivaltime is 5 minutes earlier than begintime

Comment: `arrivaltime <= logtime and logtime <= begintime` can be written `arrivaltime <= logtime <= begintime` in Python.  Means the same thing.

Comment: I think the question was about how to loop through the two lists and do this kind of check for every log entry.

Comment: Of course you can shorten it.  And I did not go into the part where you travel through the lists either...

Comment: @user2563336 The reason I didnt use datetime is that both data produce different type of date time formats and I just choose to convert both to unix timestamp because I thought that calculation can be done easily.